# Jquery and ajax - using a link to inject a files content

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to achieve the following.
I have an initially-empty absolutely positioned div (#description) sitting on TOP of another div (#zoom) which gets large images injected into it when users select one of the 15 or so thumbnails on the side of the page.

I have a link on the side such as:

```
<div id="whatisit"><a href="description.php"></div>
```

that when clicked should INJECT the "description.php" file contents into the #description div on the site. First, of course it would need to "fadeOut" what the contents of #zoom.

I have the following code which I tried to put together to do the job.

```
 <script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#whatisit a").click(function() {
        var descPath = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#zoom img").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).attr({ src:descPath }).fadeIn("slow");
      });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

It fades out the contents of #zoom, but doesn't inject or fadeIn the "descriptions.php" file content. Am I doing something wrong?  Or missing something?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use an AJAX get request, so do something like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#whatisit a").click(function() {
        var descPath = $(this).attr("href");
        $.get(descPath, function(html_returned) {
            $("#zoom img").fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $("#description").html(html_returned).fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }, "html");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This should inject the contents of description.php into #description.

Comment: this did the trick (sort of!). :)   There's just one problem - when I click on an image thumbnail (which when clicked loads a large image into #zoom), the "desription" text remains there. It should disappear.

Comment: I added a fadeOut command to another jquery js script I had and the problem was resolved.

Thank you to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you're trying to push content into a `div` by setting its `src` attribute the way you would on an image, which isn't going to do anything.  Possibly if it were an `iframe` that would be meaningful.  Otherwise, you're going to have to get a bit fancier to pull description.php's content into the div, methinks.